# ForEach with dynamic vs. static range

Tags: swiftui

I've been struggling with an-otherwise simple issue I'm sure. I can't seem to find the proper way to use ForEach with a dynamic range.

I have the following simple demo showing my issue. tapGesture on anySquare will update a @State variable array to make square 1 disappear / appear. Works like a charm on the right side but doesn't within a ForEach.

[image: before / after tap]

```
@State var visibilityArray = [true,true]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            Color.white

            HStack {
                VStack{
                    Text("Dynamic")
                    ForEach(visibilityArray.indices) { i in

                        if self.visibilityArray[i] {
                            Rectangle()
                                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                .overlay(Text(String(i)).foregroundColor(Color.white))
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation(Animation.spring()) {
                                        self.visibilityArray[1].toggle()
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                VStack{
                    Text("Static")
                    if self.visibilityArray[0] {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .overlay(Text("0").foregroundColor(Color.white))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(Animation.spring()) {
                                    self.visibilityArray[1].toggle()
                                }
                        }
                    }

                    if self.visibilityArray[1] {
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .overlay(Text("1").foregroundColor(Color.white))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                withAnimation(Animation.spring()) {
                                    self.visibilityArray[1].toggle()
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode error occurring when you try to modify your array used in a `ForEach` loop (eg. by replacing it with another array) provides a good guidance:

> `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data.
> Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)`
> and provide an explicit `id`!

You can use this code to make your `ForEach` work:

```
ForEach(visibilityArray, id: \.self) {
```

This also means that for every item in the loop you have to return some `View`. I suggest passing the filtered array (only with items you want to display/use) as an input to the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: I don't understand the required syntax to use ForEach(_:id:content:) when I do what you suggest I get "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols" because Booleans are not struct/enum/class. I was hoping I could find a way

Comment: `ForEach(visibilityArray, id: \.self) { item in ... }` is an example of `ForEach(_:id:content:)`. But in this case `item` is not an index. And for every item you have to return some View - that's why you are getting this error. `if self.visibilityArray[0]` statement means you return the View only in some cases. Rather than using if inside the loop, pass the filtered array as an input to the loop.

Comment: @pawello2222 `if self.visibilityArray[0]` is not an issue at all. `ViewBuilder` supports returning no view at all. You could even return nothing at all from the `content` closure parameter of the `ForEach`.